# @font-face doesn't allow to use local fonts in email template

Tags: html, email, fonts, webfonts

I work with a system that can use an email template to make and send an email, and I face a problem while trying to attach local font (any type) to email.

I attach a font with @font-face in  in this way (prerendered HTML):

```
 <style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "Pacifico";
    src: url("../resources/Pacifico.ttf");
}

body, span, div, input[type=text], label {
    font-family: 'Pacifico' !important;
color:red;
}
</style>
```

After rendering, ready to send HTML page contains an appropriate link to the font (I can download font successfully as a font (content type is correct) from Tomcat server localhost:8080/.../font) and it is uploaded properly. However, the page doesn't implement it and the font itself isn't represented as it should (seems like default font is used).

This problem relates exclusively to locally stored fonts - if I use any CDN email is rendered properly.

The font is 100% workable since when I create a dummy HTML page and attach font (with a direct link to a folder) there it is applied correctly.

**Edit**

May this issue to connected to the inequality of content types for fonts in Tomcat and my application (application/x-font-ttf in Tomcat for .ttf fonts VS font/ttf in application)?

**Edit 2**

Rendered HTML contains this snippet

```
<style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Pacifico";
    src: url("http://localhost:8080/path/to/resource/Pacifico.ttf");
}    
body, span, div, input[type=text], label {
    font-family: 'Pacifico' !important;
color:red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The relative URL will be relative to the location of the CSS.

Which appears to be inline in the email, which does not have a URL. So a relative URL has nothing to be relative to.

I assume when using a CDN you'll have an absolute URL: you'll need one for each non-embedded resources,

Comment: Actually, HTML contains a full path to the font in Tomcat's resource folder and I can download it without editing available URL. Or maybe I've misunderstood you?

Comment: @ryzhman I'm looking at the CSS in the question which shows a relative URL.

Comment: @ryzhman: Do you have any examples of emails that do this at all? Most mail client's are very restrictive about what HTML etc. they render, and not downloading external resources by default. You have a resource the mail client could download, but will it?

Comment: If email clients don't download external resources, how can it happen that Google fonts are uploaded and applied successfully to email templates? 
It seems to me that the algorithm is quite the same: the font is placed on some server (Google or Tomcat) and linked to a template in @font-face; on rendering it is downloaded and applied. Isn't it?

Comment: @ryzhman Different email clients are different: there ate no global standards in this area (clients in this case includes desktop apps, mobile apps, and web clients).